# reading values from txt file and passing in function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a **`txt`** file which has values **`x`** , **`y`** listed as

> 20
>
> 80
>
> 70.....

I wrote code to read the x and y but i am not sure what i am doing wrong .

```
def readTruth():
    with open("Truth.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            x_truth, y_truth = line.split("\n")
 
            return x_truth,y_truth      

def main():
    x,y = readTruth()
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I only see one value getting printed in x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading one line at a time. So you cannot access the values in the 2nd line while reading the first line. Splitting the line by the newline character "\n" will do nothing in this instance.

If you only have 2 lines in your text file, you could do something like this:

```
# Note here that I am lazy and used a string here instead of text file 
a_string = "1\n2"

def readTruth():
        x_truth, y_truth = a_string.split("\n")
        return x_truth,y_truth

x,y = readTruth()

print(x) # 1
print(y) # 2
```

But I suspect you have more than just 2 values. You could refactor your text file to hold the 2 values on the same line, separated by a space or comma. If you do so, your solution will work. You would just need to split by the comma or space, whichever delimiter you choose to use.

If you must have each number on a separate line, then your solution won't work. You would need to add the results to a list of X values and a list of Y values:

```
# truth.txt:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
#

f = open("truth.txt", "r")

def readTruth():
    counter = 1
    X_vals = []
    Y_vals = []

    for line in f.readlines():
        # If it is an even numbered line, add to Y_vals
        if counter % 2 == 0:
            Y_vals.append(line.strip("\n"))
        # Otherwise it is an odd numbered line, so add to X_vals
        else:
            X_vals.append(line.strip("\n"))
        counter+=1

    return X_vals, Y_vals
            
x,y = readTruth()
print(x) # ['1', '3']
print(y) # ['2', '4']
```

Based on comments from the question poster, I assume they have a blank line between each number in their text file. This means each number is on an odd numbered line. The quick solution, added onto my previous example, is to skip blank lines:

```
# truth.txt:
# 1
#
# 2
#
# 3
#
# 4
#

f = open("truth.txt", "r")

def readTruth():
    counter = 1
    X_vals = []
    Y_vals = []

    for line in f.readlines():
        # Skip blank lines
        if line.strip("\n") != "":
            # If it is an even numbered line, add to Y_vals
            if counter % 2 == 0:
                Y_vals.append(line.strip("\n"))
            # Otherwise it is an odd numbered line, so add to X_vals
            else:
                X_vals.append(line.strip("\n"))
            counter+=1

    return X_vals, Y_vals
            
x,y = readTruth()
print(x) # ['1', '3']
print(y) # ['2', '4']
```

Comment: thanks , but with this code all elements are in x and there is nothing in y                       print(x) # ['1', '3']
print(y) # ['2', '4']

Comment: What does your text file look like? If everything is in X when you used this code, then that means all of your values are on an odd numbered line. Do you have a blank line between each number?

Comment: If you have a blank line after each number, just skip the blank lines. See the 3rd example I just added.

Comment: i have another question i was trying to get std devcaition of x and Y                  
   std_x_truth =  numpy.std(x)
   std_y_truth =  numpy.std(y)  but i am  getting error

Comment: is this correct represntation                                                                                                 
   a = np.asarray(x_truth).astype(np.int64)
   std_x_truth = np.std(a)

Comment: You should post a new question. I have barely used numpy and don't know much about it. I mainly use python for scripting tasks that would take me a long time to do manually.

Answer (score -1):

We obtain the values ​​of X and Y:

```
def readTruth(): 
    with open("Truth.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            x_truth, y_truth = line.split("\n")
        
            return x_truth,y_truth
def main():
    x,y = readTruth()
    print("Var_X = "+ str(x[0]))
    print("Var_Y = "+ str(x[1]))
```

You can put the variables in a list for each X and Y

Comment: i have just one column

Comment: Edit my answer, look. :)

Comment: is return x_truth,y_truth in the for loop , if it is then i get wrong answer if the first variable in text file is 297 i am seeing out put as 2 and 9